# NameError: name '...' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm writing a code for power flow under PYPOWER.BUT I can't create my own file because of the following error.

```
savecase(fname = mggg.py,ppc = ppc)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-131-900829d7478d>", line 1, in <module>
    savecase(fname = mggg.py,ppc = ppc)

NameError: name 'mggg' is not defined
```

The source code of savecase can be found at http://rwl.github.io/PYPOWER/api/pypower.savecase-pysrc.html

Where is my error?? Could you please help me fix this? Thanks

The following error occur when I use str.

```
savecase(fname = r'mggg',ppc = ppc)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-137-896303d532b9>", line 1, in <module>
    savecase(fname = r'mggg',ppc = ppc)

  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-   packages\pypower\savecase.py", line 116, in savecase
    fd.write('def %s():\n' % basename(rootname))

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: To provide the filename as a string it has to look like this `'mggg.py'`, not `mggg.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fname argument of the savecase function probably requires a string.
Try like this:

```
savecase(fname = 'mggg.py',ppc = ppc)
```

Comment: I have tried the str form,but there is a another error.

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: `bytes-like object is required` is different problem so your first proble was solved (and you should create new question with new problem). It can be problem because this module was created for Python 2.x not for Python 3 which may expect `bytes-like object` instead of `str` when it write file opened with "wb" - bytes mode (see in code `fd = open(fname, "wb")`)

Comment: Thanks,@furas. I posted the new error above.Could you have some solution?

Comment: As I said above - module was created for python 2.5+ and you use Python 3. You can try use `"w"` instead of `"wb"` in `fd = open(fname, "wb")` in `savecase.py`. Maybe it help. But you may expect more problems. You should have program `2to3` (installed with Python 3) which tries convert Python 2 code to Python 3 and can resolve some problems.

Comment: Both of you are right. Thank you all very much.@Maze88  @furas.I installed anaconda 2.7 and the problem is solved.